# Export excel using xlsx in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, xlsx

I am trying to export .xlsx file using angular 8(with xlsx library). Its working fine for simple worksheer but not able to add page title, and dated in a row and also not able to merge the cells.

In service:

```js
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
      
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
```

```js
private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}

in component: 

    public export() {
    console.log('export clicked');
    this._excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.exportData, 'rakesh');
  }
```

I need the exported worksheet would be as
[image]

please advise what I am doing or missing something.

Comment: hi this is well documents in the docs [see docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)